# jQuery Find and Replace String with HTML tag in it

Tags: jquery, html, replace

**What Im trying to do**

I am trying to copy some text in a div to a Textarea. During this copying, I need to find an replace a number with another number.

**This is my HTML**

```
<DateTo>31MAR17</DateTo>
```

I want to find `17</DateTo>` and replace with `20</DateTo>` and then paste it into the Textarea.

This is my Fiddle. This works fine without the `</DateTo>` bit, but when I add it, it doesn't work. Can you guys please help me on this?

**FIDDLE :** https://jsfiddle.net/c2fny59x/12/

Note : The html tag must be in the find, replace sequence.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
var leftContent = $(".leftPart").text().replace("17", "20");
```

with

```
var leftContent = $(".leftPart").html().replace("17</dateto>", "20</dateto>");
```

note that to get the actual html tags you need to use html() not text(), and that jQuery will force all html tags to lower case in the process.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesnt work. It shows all the HTML tags in the textarea.

Comment: you can set a hidden element's .html(leftContent)  and then take its .text() to re-strip the html.